# Can I pass JobParameters like current-time to SimpleJobLauncher?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am trying to launch a Spring batch job with SimpleJobLauncher. How can I pass JobParameters to it? Or jobParameters cannot be passed to SimpleJobLauncher?

Comment: org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to pass current time as a job parameter , but yes you can pass it as one of the job parameter and it can be accseed throughout the spring batch components ,like tasklet , writers and readers .

Comment: If I dont pass any parameters, it doesnt run after the first run. On the second run, it says job is already completed. How do I make the job scheduled to run everytime it being invoked?